# Why in my JSON array is just last json element?

Tags: java, json, gson

Why in my JSON array is just last json element?

This is my code:

```
@GET
@Path("inregistrareHarta")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void getListPuncte(@QueryParam("idTransporturi") int idTransporturi) 
{
  PuncteDAO puncteInformation = new PuncteDAO();
  ArrayList<Puncte> puncteList = puncteInformation.getPuncte(idTransporturi);

  Gson gson = new Gson();
  JsonArray arrayObj=new JsonArray();
  for(int i=0;i<puncteList.size();i++)
  {
    Puncte puncte = puncteList.get(i);
    JsonElement puncteObj = gson.toJsonTree(puncte);   
    arrayObj.add(puncteObj);
  }
  JsonObject myObj = new JsonObject();
  myObj.add("puncteList", arrayObj);
  System.out.println(myObj.toString());
}
```

This is the result I'm getting:

```
{"puncteList":
  [
    {"idPuncte":7,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":190.0,"longitudine":150.0,"descriere":"2_4"},
    {"idPuncte":7,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":190.0,"longitudine":150.0,"descriere":"2_4"},
    {"idPuncte":7,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":190.0,"longitudine":150.0,"descriere":"2_4"},
    {"idPuncte":7,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":190.0,"longitudine":150.0,"descriere":"2_4"}
  ]
}
```

And this is the result I'm expecting:

```
{"puncteList":
  [ 
    {"idPuncte":4,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":19.0,"longitudine":0.0,"descriere": "‌2_1"}, 
    {"idPuncte":5,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":10.0,"longitudine": 50.0,"descriere":"‌2_2"}, 
    {"idPuncte":6,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":1.0,"longitudine":1.0,"descriere":"2_‌3"},
    {"idPuncte":7,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":30.0,"longitudine":50.0,"descriere":"‌2_4"}
  ]
}
```

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: It seems that the problem must be in the data, not in the JSON parsing... did you debug to see what's inside `puncteList` before starting your parsing?

Comment: And I return puncteList that is an ArrayList

Comment: Let Gson do the work, there's no need for a loop here: `JsonArray arrayObj = gson.toJsonTree(puncte).getAsJsonArray();`.

Comment: Looking at the overall code, you could also just have a `class PuncteList { List<Puncte> puncteList; }` and have `getListPuncte(...)` return an actual `PunceList` object -- your JAX-RS framework should be able to convert POJOs to JSON for you. Also frees your business logic from JSON code and it's easier to test.

Answer (score 0):

In your expected output the closing ] is probably a typo.

Your expected output is simple not a valid JSON expression. You can have this :

```
[
  "puncteList", 
  {"idPuncte":4,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":19.0,"longitudine":0.0,"descriere": "‌2_1"}, 
  {"idPuncte":5,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":10.0,"longitudine": 50.0,"descriere":"‌2_2"}, 
  {"idPuncte":6,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":1.0,"longitudine":1.0,"descriere":"2_‌3"},
  {"idPuncte":7,"idTransport":2,"latitudine":30.0,"longitudine":50.0,"descriere":"‌2_4"}
]
```

But, if "puncteList" is a key it must have a value: a scalar, an array or another object.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid either, since puncteList is a key with no associated value. I guess you meant 'But, if "puncteList" is a **key** name'

Comment: @Peter, there was a open [ as well, but I accidentally deleted it in my edit, it's corrected now... the problem is with the values inside the JSON, I understand... the JSON is valid.

Comment: @MikeO: Ok, right now I see what you mean. Probably `puncteInformation.getPuncte(idTransporturi);` is not returning what you expected.

Comment: This is my query with date:public ArrayList<Puncte> getPuncte(int idTrans) {
ArrayList<Puncte>puncteList = new ArrayList<Puncte>();
Puncte puncte=new Puncte();ps = con.prepareStatement("SELECT... puncte_transport where puncte_transport.idTrans="+idTrans);
rs = ps.executeQuery();
while (rs.next()) {
puncte.setIdPuncte(rs.getInt("idPuncte"));    puncte.setIdTransport(rs.getInt("idTransporturi"));
puncte.setLatitudine(rs.getDouble("latitudine"));   puncte.setLongitudine(rs.getDouble("longitudine"));    puncte.setDescriere(rs.getString("descriere"));
puncteList.add(puncte); }
return puncteList;}

Comment: I solved it!My mistake was that i declare Puncte puncte=new Puncte() outside of while!Thanks a lot for your help!